# how can I check two groups in a regular expression are equal inside the match function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an interval information like "Sat 8-11, Sat 11-18" and I want to check if the second hour in the first interval (11) equals to the first hour in the second interval (11), then merge this two hours into one "Sat 8-18".
That would be great if anyone gives me a hint.

Comment: do you have something like `'Fri 8-12'` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `replace` using back references:

```js
var s = "Sat 8-11, Sat 11-18";

s = s.replace(/([a-z]+) (\d+)-(\d+), \1 \3-/i, "$1 $2-");
console.log(s);
```

Comment: very smart! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.prototype.match()` function with specific regex pattern:

```js
var s = "Sat 8-11, Sat 11-18",
    r = s.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+) (\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2}), \1 (\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/);

// if the input string matches the pattern and the second hour 
// in the first interval equals to the first hour in the second interval 
if (r.length == 6 && r[3] == r[4]) {
    s = r[1] +' '+ r[2] +'-'+ r[5];
}
console.log(s)
```